# Relationship among futures, options and stock prices

Tags: cointegration, finance, vector-error-correction-model, granger-causality, eviews

I have the data of past 10 years of NIFTY (the National Stock Exchange of India) stock, futures and options and I want to show the lead-lag relationship (which reacts first, futures, options or stocks) among the three using cointegration test, VECM model and granger's causalty.

The issue is that I don't know how to use the options data because it has both call and put out of the money in the money, and at the money prices on all days for different expiry everyday, but there's multiple data to use for any given day.

I have to perform time-series statistical analysis on the data, so I need to have only one price for one day. Given this issue, how can I perform the tests mentioned above? I am using E-views to perform these tests. I just want help to get around the options data.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, could you edit to make it more verbose? Moreover, please do not write in ALL CAPS.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to find the relationship among stocks and european options, if the stocks lead the options or vice versa. And since european options have in the money, at the money and out of the money options for different expiries everyday, there's multiple data to use for one day and I have to time-series statistics. I just want help to get around the options data.

Comment: @Tim I've edited my question. Please open the question.

Comment: OK, re-opened it, but honestly I do not find the question very clear and if that was also the case for other users, it diminishes chances of this getting answered. Editing it for more details would help.

Comment: @Tim what other details do you think are mandatory to get my query answered?

Comment: Nothing is "mandatory", just if people understand what you mean better, it'd be easier for them to answer it. Many questions get ignored if they sound unclear.

Comment: You first sentence spans over 6 lines. Splitting it into 3-5 simple sentences of normal length could help.

Comment: @RichardHardy the post has been edited.

Comment: It looks like a finance question, not a statistical one, because answering it requires understanding what the different derivatives (in the financial sense of the term) are. Consider posting it on Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit for Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange and has already been [posted there](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54887).